# How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements depending on the previous sibling using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I want to wrap all the appendix elements, but only if the first appendix element's preceding sibling is part.

So if the input is like

```
<part>
..
..
</part>
<appendix href="..">
</appendix>
<appendix href="..">
</appendix>
```

Then the output is like

```
<part>
..
..
</part>
<appendices>
  <appendix href="..">
  </appendix>
  <appendix href="..">
  </appendix>
</appendices>
```

I'm fairly new to XSLT. So all that I've tried has failed till now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain whether you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 as grouping is easier in XSLT 2.0. You also need to provide more details on the possible input, can there be different type of input documents, one type that has the structure you have shown, others of a different structure that you don't want to transform at all? Or are there more elements in a single input document?

Comment: Yes, I'm using XSLT 2.0 with a Saxon processor. There can be two output's. One is the structure shown above and another is one where there is no <part> but instead has a <chapter> for which no processing need be done.

Comment: Also, there are much more elements than just these mentioned above. Hence, using `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` gives a conflict with another template that starts with `<xsl:template match="*">` which is used to lowecase all elements in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 your verbal description translates into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[appendix]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::appendix)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::part]">
                        <appendices>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </appendices>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention this in my question, but there are other templates like `<xsl:template match="*">` which conflict with `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">`. Any workaround for that?

Comment: If you get a warning about an "ambiguous rule match" then you need to apply a priority for the template you want to have precedence e.g. `<xsl:template match="*" priority="5">...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: Sorry about this, but this does not seem to work for me. The code seems to be running but I guess one of the few other templates modying the appendix element is messing up. @Martin Honnen

Comment: Well if you need help integrating the suggested code into other code then edit your question and present the code.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer because this code works. Just needed to tweak it a little bit with my requirements for integration. Thanks so much @Martin Honnen